# Simple HTTP(S) Response on WebSocket (WSS) Server

Tags: node.js, websocket, browser, https, response

I am running a websocket (wss) server (with certificate) on port 443. For this i am using the "https" and "ws" module in nodejs (simplified):

```
require(__dirname + './config.js');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocketServer = require('ws');
const server = new https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./fullchain.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({server: server});
wss.on("connection", function(socket){
    const c_inst = new require('./client.js');
    const thisClient = new c_inst();
    thisClient.socket = socket;
    thisClient.initiate();
    socket.on('error', thisClient.error);
    socket.on('close', thisClient.end);
    socket.on('message', thisClient.data);
});
server.listen(config.port, config.ip);
```

The wss communication works perfect! But if i open the wss url via https:// in the browser i get a timeout error (Error code 524) because there is no response for a "normal" (https/get) request.

How can i implement a response for this case in my wss server?
I just want to send a response with a simple text or html like "This is a websocket server" or do a redirect to another url if someone connects to the wss socket via browser/https.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for HTTPS server on node.
https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener

You need to add request listener when you create a server.

```js
const server = new https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./fullchain.pem')
    },
    (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('This is a websocket server\n');
        // do redirects or whanever you want
    }
);
```